# should pass resolved pixel dimension instead of resource id here:getResource().getDimession*(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

Tags: android

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_item_talker_realm);
textView.setText(skill.skill_name);
textView.setTextSize(12);
textView.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.userIndexTagText));

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 15, 15);
```

I want to add `MarginLayoutParams` to my view. But, It shows an error

> should pass resolved pixel dimension instead of resource id here:`getResource().getDimession*(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

`MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` are indeed valid input for `LayoutParams` width and height.

This is hyperactive [Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html) in action. You can safely ignore the warning.

Select the underlined statement, press Alt+Enter, select the issue, select Ignore for statement/for method.